# How to increase dogs/minute?

Tags: competitive-eating

I was watching the [2023 Hot Dog Eating Contest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AI5nCkE1xM), and I noticed the "dogs/minute" metric.

How would one go about increasing this number? I would think keeping this number consistent would yield more HDB over the span of 10 minutes compared to eating as much as you can as fast as you can.

[image: DOGS/MINUTE]

Comment: Could you please clarify the table?  If Chestnut has eaten 26 hotdogs, and the timer is at 7 minutes 11 seconds ( 7.183 minutes) then it would be 3.62 hotdogs/minute.

Comment: If Chestnut has eaten 9.23 hotdogs per minute and has eaten 26, then the timer would be around 2.81 minutes or 2 min 49 seconds.

Comment: Why is Weaver halfway between 14 and 15?   (possibly because of a screen grab while animated)

Comment: @Criggie Maybe there is visible sign of one dog coming up after being eaten? :)  BTW, I do wonder whether competitive eating is really a sport.  Shall we accept questions on competitive flatulence passing as well?

Comment: Feel free to bring it up on Sports Meta, but I don't see anybody claim to run the International Federation of Competition Farting. @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket

Comment: @Criggie The timer is counting down from 10 minutes, which confirms your second comment (as 2 min 49 sec from a 10 minute countdown timer is 7 min 11 sec).

Comment: @Nij I have mixed emotions about competitive eating.  We literally have millions of people starving in our world, so competitive eating seems like a horrible practice.  At the same time, I can't deny experiencing mild amusement when I once watched a 20 second clip of a contest.  Same true of a farting contest, so there you go.  My only true joy generated from eating contests is due to the ***fictional*** blueberry pie scene in the acclaimed movie *Stand By Me*.  If you haven't seen it, I highly recommend that film.  Just perhaps don't eat supper while watching that scene. ;)